Why does cloning list code from markdown-it not cause the same behvior
I want to change the list rule in markdown-it so that I can write +/- lists:
 + sunny
 + upside
 - downside

Markdown treats this is 2 lists, so wnat to change this. I tried many simple ways to get this done but failed. Now I thought I simply copy the list code from markdown-it repo and then I modify that code. I assumed that copying the code https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/blob/master/lib/rules_block/list.mjs holding
export default function mylist(state, startLine, endLine, silent) ... // renamed it to mylist

and configuring
md.block.ruler.at('list', mylist)

would give me default behavior, and I have the list code under control and can modify it then. Surprisingly instead of lists it renders
<ul><li><p>sunny + upside - downside</p>
<ul><li>haha - hoho</li></ul></li></ul>

Why does this configuration not cause default behavior?
Hints to another way to get the task done are also welcome.
